# How to do AVX-512 integer increment only if element is non zero

Tags: c++, avx512

I have to add a value to the elements of an AVX register if and only if the value of the element is non-zero.  Below is the code that I have, but it seems like I have to go to a lot of extra trouble and like there should be a better way to do this. The commented out loop is the plain c++ expression of what I want to do.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

uint32_t make_bit_mask(bool T0 = 0, bool T1 = 0, bool T2 = 0, bool T3 = 0,
    bool T4 = 0, bool T5 = 0, bool T6 = 0, bool T7 = 0,
    bool T8 = 0, bool T9 = 0, bool T10 = 0, bool T11 = 0,
    bool T12 = 0, bool T13 = 0, bool T14 = 0, bool T15 = 0,
    bool T16 = 0, bool T17 = 0, bool T18 = 0, bool T19 = 0,
    bool T20 = 0, bool T21 = 0, bool T22 = 0, bool T23 = 0,
    bool T24 = 0, bool T25 = 0, bool T26 = 0, bool T27 = 0,
    bool T28 = 0, bool T29 = 0, bool T30 = 0, bool T31 = 0)
{
    return  ((T0 << 0) | (T1 << 1) | (T2 << 2) | (T3 << 3) |
        (T4 << 4) | (T5 << 5) | (T6 << 6) | (T7 << 7) |
        (T8 << 8) | (T9 << 9) | (T10 << 10) | (T11 << 11) |
        (T12 << 12) | (T13 << 13) | (T14 << 14) | (T15 << 15) |
        (T16 << 16) | (T17 << 17) | (T18 << 18) | (T19 << 19) |
        (T20 << 20) | (T21 << 21) | (T22 << 22) | (T23 << 23) |
        (T24 << 24) | (T25 << 25) | (T26 << 26) | (T27 << 27) |
        (T28 << 28) | (T29 << 29) | (T30 << 30) | (T31 << 31));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint16_t> testValues{0};
    testValues.resize(65'536);
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < testValues.size(); i += 4)
    {
        testValues[i] = static_cast<uint16_t>(i);
    }
    auto start{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };
    auto oneRegister{ _mm512_set1_epi16(1) };
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < testValues.size(); i += 32)
    {
        uint32_t loadMask{ make_bit_mask(testValues[i],testValues[i + 1],testValues[i + 2],testValues[i + 3],
                                            testValues[i + 4],testValues[i + 5],testValues[i + 6],testValues[i + 7],
                                            testValues[i + 8],testValues[i + 9],testValues[i + 10],testValues[i + 11],
                                            testValues[i + 12],testValues[i + 13],testValues[i + 14],testValues[i + 15],
                                            testValues[i + 16],testValues[i + 17],testValues[i + 18],testValues[i + 19],
                                            testValues[i + 20],testValues[i + 21],testValues[i + 22],testValues[i + 23],
                                            testValues[i + 24],testValues[i + 25],testValues[i + 26],testValues[i + 27],
                                            testValues[i + 28],testValues[i + 29],testValues[i + 30],testValues[i + 31])
        };
        _mm512_storeu_epi16(&testValues[i], _mm512_mask_add_epi16(_mm512_loadu_epi16(&testValues[i]),
            (__mmask32)loadMask, _mm512_loadu_epi16(&testValues[i]), oneRegister ));
    }
    /*
    for (auto& iter : testValues)
    {
        if (iter)
            iter += 1;
    }
    */
    auto end{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };
    std::cout << "Summation took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is because the compiler is doing the same thing behind the scenes or if it is because my make_bit_mask is so expensive to do.  But there isn't much of a difference in performance between the explicit AVX version and the iterator version of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to increment every non-zero element in a vector?  (You're not actually summing the elements in one vector, just doing vertical addition).

It sounds like your real problem is turning an integer array into a mask, according to elements being non-zero.  AVX-512 has instructions for this, e.g. compare vs. 0, or more specifically [`vptestmw k1, zmm,zmm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vptestmb:vptestmw:vptestmd:vptestmq) to create a mask according to each element being non-zero.  (`v & v` is just `v`, so you can pass the same operand twice to bypass the AND operation).

```
  __m512i v = _mm512_loadu_si512(&testValues[i]);
  __mmask32 nonzeros = _mm512_test_epi16_mask(v,v);
  v = _mm512_mask_sub_epi16(v, nonzeros, v, _mm512_set1_epi16(-1));  // set1(-1) is cheaper than 1
```

Or for other values,

```
 v = _mm512_mask_add_epi16(v, nonzeros, v, _mm512_set1_epi16( increment ));
```

In a function, `gcc -O2 -march=skylake-avx512` [compiles it like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Enzb4ee88):

```
foo(unsigned short const*):
        vmovdqu64       zmm0, ZMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        vpternlogd      zmm1, zmm1, zmm1, 0xFF       # set1(-1)
        vptestmw        k1, zmm0, zmm0
        vpsubw  zmm0{k1}, zmm0, zmm1
        ret
```

The `set1(-1)` will be hoisted out of the loop by the compiler.

---

Fun fact: clang will transform `add(v, set1(1))` into `sub(v, set1(-1))` for you, but GCC misses that optimization.

---

Without AVX-512, (just AVX2 or SSE2) you can create a `0` or `-1` vector with a compare.  Unfortunately, before AVX-512 we only have `cmpeq` and `cmpgt`, not `cmpne`, so we need to invert that `0 / -1`

```
  __m256i v = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)&testValues[i]);
  __m256i nonzeros = _mm256_cmpeq_epi16(v, _mm256_setzero_si256());
  nonzeros = _mm256_xor_si256(nonzeros, _mm256_set1_epi32(-1)); 
          // or add 1 to turn 0->1 and -1->0 to use add()
  v = _mm256_sub_epi16(v, nonzeros);
```

For arbitrary constants, you can `_mm256_andnot_si256(nonzeros, _mm256_set1_epi16( increment ))` to create a vector that's 0 for v=0 elements, and `increment` for non-zero.

Comment: I am wanting to add a constant values to the non zero elements of an AVX register.  The 1 is just a stand in for the real value, so it will be a _mm512_set1, just with a different value. 
But thank you, that seems to be a much better version of what I wanted!  I knew there had to be an intrinsic for it, just couldn't find it, thanks again!

Comment: @MatthewPittenger: BTW, your comment on harold's answer seemed to take it personally.  The "epic disaster" comment is a realistic evaluation of how good a job GCC did, for a function that *could* have been auto-vectorized to one asm instruction.  Or if not auto-vectorized, it could still have done a less terrible job with the scalar code, using shift/OR instead of spilling.  I'm pretty sure harold wasn't intending to insult you for writing it as an example of what you want.  "epic disaster" is also a realistic description of how it affects the performance of your actual loop.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah there is a simpler way. Put simply there are binary literals in c++ 17 or later. If you can use that?

Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t value = 0b1010'0100'0001'1100'0100'0011'1010'0010;
    //do whatever with value...
}
```

Comment: The problem is I won't know what values are in the AVX register until runtime.  That's why I have to make the bitmask from the elements that are loaded into the AVX register.