# Packed bit test for __m512

Tags: x86-64, intrinsics, avx512

There is no intrinsic for __m512 packed bit test (like `_mm512_testz_si512`).

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`_mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v) == 0` is the drop-in replacement.**

Test-into-mask and then test the mask to get a scalar `bool` you can branch on or whatever. The element-size of the test doesn't matter if you only care about whether the whole vector has a non-zero bit anywhere, but element sizes of 8/16/32/64 are available ([asm manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vptestmb:vptestmw:vptestmd:vptestmq) / [Intrinsic guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&text=vptestm)).

You can also just use the mask as a 0 or non-zero integer if you don't want to branch on it right away and don't *need* to convert it to a `bool`, or if you want to know where the set bits are (bit-scan or popcount.)  Or use it to zero-mask or merge-mask other AVX-512 operations.

```cpp
    __mmask16 mask == _mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v);   // 0 or non-zero integer
    if (mask != 0) {  // __mmask16 is in practice an alias for uint16_t
          // You might have further use for the mask, e.g.
          int first_match_index = std::countr_zero(mask);
    }
```

In asm, the test/branch or getting a GPR integer could look like this:

```
  vptestmd  k0, zmm1, zmm1     ; mask of elements where zmm1&zmm1 was non-zero.

; branch on it.  Or a compiler might use cmovz or setz (create an actual bool)
  kortestw  k0, k0             ; set integer FLAGS according to k0|k0
  jz        vec_was_all_zero   ; branch if ZF==1

; or get a 0 / non-0  int  you can return, or bit-scan to find the first non-zero element
  kmovw     eax, k0
```

Or depending on what you want to do with the mask, `_mm512_testn_epi32_mask(v,v)` to get NAND instead of AND.  `testn(v,v) == ~test(v,v)`.  But if you just want to test the mask, you could do `_mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v) == 0xFFFF` to check that all 16 elements had a non-zero bit, instead of checking that the `testn` result was 0.  Actually compilers are bad at this; you need to use `_kortestc_mask16_u8(msk,msk)`  ([intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&ig_expand=796,3668&text=kortest)) instead of `msk == 0xFFFF` to get compilers to make efficient asm ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aint+test(__m512i+v)%7B%0A++++return+_mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v)%3B+//+__mmask16+zero-extends+to+int%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+test_all_nonzero(__m512i+v)%7B%0A++++uint16_t+msk+%3D+_mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v)%3B++//+clang+uses+vptestnmd+and+checks+the+mask+for+0%0A++++return+msk+%3D%3D+0xFFFFu%3B+++++++++++++++++++++++//+GCC+uses+kmov+to+get+the+mask+into+a+GPR%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+test_all_nonzero_v2(__m512i+v)%7B%0A++++uint16_t+msk+%3D+_mm512_test_epi32_mask(v,v)%3B%0A++++return+_kortestc_mask16_u8(msk,msk)%3B++//+hand-hold+GCC+into+using+the+CF+result+from+kortestw%0A++++//+aka+_mm512_kortestc+-+it+looks+like+the+initial+design+didn!%27t+leave+room+for+names+for+different+mask+widths,+but+width+matters+for+the+all-ones+check%0A++++//+there!%27s+also+a+version+that+returns+the+ZF+result+and+produces+a+by-reference+CF+result+so+you+can+encourage+the+compiler+to+kortest+once+and+use+both+outputs.%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:55.88712109133899,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:4,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dx86-64-v4%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:44.11287890866101,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:3,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dx86-64-v4%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:100,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).

[`kortest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/kortestw:kortestb:kortestq:kortestd) sets the carry flag if the OR result is all-ones, so you actually can test for all-set as cheaply as all-clear for any mask width, so this is efficiently possible even without an immediate operand like you'd use for AVX2 `_mm256_movemask_epi8(v) == -1` where a compiler would `cmp eax, -1`, which is slightly larger code-size than `test eax,eax`.

So it mostly matters to avoid inverting the mask before `countr_zero` or whatever; branching can still be done without needing a `kmov` to a GPR first, unless you leave it up to current compilers.

---

**AVX-512 compares and tests are only available with a mask register as a destination (`k0-k7`)**, kind of like a compare + `vpmovmskb` rolled into one single-uop instruction.  (`_mm256_movemask_epi8` or `ps/pd`.  The AVX-512 versions of those, extracting the high bit of each element, are [`vpmovd2m`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovb2m:vpmovw2m:vpmovd2m:vpmovq2m) (`_mm512_movepi32_mask`), available for every element size including 16-bit, e.g. to grab the sign bits of ints or floats.)

After you get a mask, there are two instructions for setting integer FLAGS conditions based on a `k` register: [`kortest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/kortestw:kortestb:kortestq:kortestd) (set FLAGS according to a bitwise OR of 2 masks, or a mask with itself), and AVX512DQ/BW [`ktest`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ktestw:ktestb:ktestq:ktestd) (... AND of 2 masks ...).

So you can actually test two vectors at once for having any non-zero elements, like

```
 __mmask16 mask1 = _mm512_test_epi32_mask(v1,v1);
 __mmask16 mask2 = _mm512_test_epi32_mask(v2,v2);
 // or any other condition you want to check, like _mm512_cmple_epu32(x,y)
 if (mask1 | mask2) {
    // At least one was non-zero; sort out which if it matters.
    // Or maybe concatenate them (e.g. kunpckwd) and bit-scan the 32-bit mask
    //  to find an element index, maybe into memory they were loaded from
 }
```

This would compile to 2x `vptestmd` and 1x `kortestw`.  Same number of uops as vector OR + one `vptestmd` + `kortest` in this case; being able to check for any set bits in either of two masks is maybe useful with more complicated compares, like for exact equality.

---

SSE4 / AVX `ptest` into integer FLAGS was always 2 uops on mainstream Intel CPUs anyway (https://uops.info/).  Intrinsics like `_mm256_testz_si256` expose various FLAGS conditions you can check, in this case ZF==1, getting the compiler to emit an instruction like `jz`, `jnz`, `cmovz ecx, edx`, or `setz al`, depending on how you use the resulting `bool`.

One of the benefits of legacy-SSE `ptest` (not overwriting a source register) doesn't exist with AVX 3-operand instructions, but it was still occasionally useful to get AND or ANDN result when the input vectors weren't compare results or other all-0 / all-1 masks.  (compare + ptest + jcc is worse than compare / pmovmskb / macro-fused `test+jcc` which is 3 total uops).

AVX-512 is heavily designed around per-element masking (so for example instead of just widening `_mm256_xor_si256` to 512, we have `_mm512_xor_epi32` or `64` as the no-mask version of `_mm512_maskz_and_epi32`.  Similarly, the AVX-512 version of `ptest` is now a per-element thing into a mask registers.  Other than scalar FP compares into EFLAGS like `vucomisd`, AVX-512 regularized things so compares/tests always go into mask registers, not EFLAGS like `ptest` or general-purpose registers like `pmovmskb`.

Related:

- [How to do AVX-512 integer increment only if element is non zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400219/how-to-do-avx-512-integer-increment-only-if-element-is-non-zero) shows an example of `vptestmw` (`_mm512_test_epi16_mask(v,v)`) to get a mask of where elements
- [Missing AVX-512 intrinsics for masks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167997/missing-avx-512-intrinsics-for-masks) - since I mentioned mask vector operations like `kunpckwd`.  Normally it's up to the compiler to decide whether to `kmov` masks to integer regs (and back if you use them as AVX-512 masks again).